# C# marshalling char* to StringBuilder get always empty string

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, stringbuilder

I am developing a C++ library and a C# application that should consume it.
The library takes two numeric input arguments and one string output parameter.
My problem is that in the C# application i get always an empty string for this parameter. Here is my code.

---

C++ side:

```
    typedef struct sharedItem{
unsigned int tagId;
unsigned char tagValue[256];
}sharedItem;


extern "C" {
int getSharedMemoryVariable(char* value, unsigned int variableTagId, int foundVariables)
{
    sharedItem *item;

        set item properly...

        strcpy(value, (char *)item->tagValue);

        check result and return properly...
}
```

}

---

C# side

```
    [DllImport("C:\\SharedMemory.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int getSharedMemoryVariable(StringBuilder variableValue, UInt16 variableTagId, Int16 foundVariables);

    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder(256);
    res = SharedMemory.getSharedMemoryVariable(value, 45, 14730);
```

My problem is that variable value is always an empty string. Please note that, in C++ side, if I replace

```
strcpy(value, (char *)item->tagValue);
```

with

```
strcpy(value, "test");
```

the application works fine.
I hope somebody can help me.
Thank you

Comment: Did you try to use `string` instead of `StringBuilder`?

Comment: You could try to use `[Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder variableValue`. It tells the runtime exactly what to do. Not sure if it helps, but it won't hurt either.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

> [DllImport] already pins parameters; and there's no need for unsafe code

Thanks @dan

Anyway that can be fixed by doing a `memset(item->tagValue, '\0', 256*sizeof(char));`

Comment: @Dan Can you point to a reference that verifies that? https://manski.net/2012/06/pinvoke-tutorial-pinning-part-4/ implies that I was correct and that infact DllImport is not in fact pinning the parameters.